# What is the difference between Groovy's AnnotationNode and Java's annotation?

Tags: java, groovy, annotations

I've written a library in which I do some introspection on Java fields to have their annotation list (and more specifically to see if they have one or more specific annotations (like - say, `@Id`, `@Child`, `@Parent`). Here is an example of the kind of code I use :

```
    @Override
    public <T extends Annotation> T getAnnotation(Class<T> annotationClass) {
        return mapped.getAnnotation(annotationClass);
    }
```

Where `mapped` is a Java [Field](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html) (and as a consequence has a [`getAnnotation(Annotation)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html) method). I want to port this method to Groovy.

I've already have understood that using Groovy, I have to replace my Fields (or bean properties) by [MetaProperties](http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi/groovy/lang/MetaProperty.html). however, I face an issue considering the use of these annotations, as it seems that groovy handles them very differently from Java.

So, is it possible to consider a migration path from Java annotations to Groovy AnnotationNode, or will i have to create an abstraction over those concepts ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about AnnotationNode.  Based on the package it's in, I'd assume it has to do with [AST Transformations](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Compile-time+Metaprogramming+-+AST+Transformations).

In any case, your code should work in Groovy the same as Java.  I use JPA in Groovy and have accessed the annotations via Java reflection. If you're having a specific problem, please provide more detail.

You seem confused about "fields" vs "metaProperties".  You don't change your fields into metaProperties. Your fields become metaProperties.  In other words, a field on a Groovy class is a bean property by default ( you get the getter/setter for free).  You can access the properties dynamically using Groovy but they are still Field's in the bytecode.

Below is a little Groovy script demonstrating accessing a bean property and getting it's annotation.

```
import java.lang.reflect.*

class Person {

  @Deprecated
  String name

}

def me = new Person(name:'dave')

assert me.name == 'dave'
assert me.'name' == 'dave'
assert me.getName() == 'dave'

assert Person.class.getDeclaredField('name') instanceof Field
assert Person.class.getDeclaredField('name').getAnnotations()
assert Person.class.getDeclaredField('name').getAnnotation(Deprecated.class)
```